# scanning a portion of webapage using htmlagilitypack and C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, html-agility-pack

I want to scan a portion of the webpage for specific URLs using htmlagilitypack and C#. How can I do it? For example I would like to scan only the links of the ads from this page http://www.olx.in/mobile-phones-cat-831 and not all the links.

Comment: `only the links of the ads`, First define how you can differentiate ads from other links, then write code to find these links(There are millions of HAP samples here on SO), if then you get stuck somewhere, ask here.

Comment: Dear @EZI I have written already the code which grabs the links. but it grabs all the links. I just want to get the links of the ads posted on that page. I am unable to construct the pattern to select that nodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like each of the Add links is nested inside a div with a specific class (`adListDetails`), so one can look for any links inside a div with said class. That would look like this:

```
 var nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[class='@adListDetails']//a[@src]");
 foreach (var node in nodes)
 {
     string src = node.Attributes["src"].Value;
 }
```

Learn more [XPath from a source like w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/).